# Как уменьшить, сузить и центрировать тело документа в фреймовой структуре?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Как центрировать и уменьшить ширину тела аналогично *marginheight/topmargin/marginwidth/leftmargin* в HTML или *margin/padding* в CSS в фреймовой структуре?

```
<frameset frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0" cols="265,*">
    <frame SRC="frame1.html" name="page">
    <frameset rows="165,*">
        <frame SRC="frame2.html" name="menu1" marginwidth="0">
        <frame SRC="frame3.html" name="menu2" marginwidth="0">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

[image: 1]

-->
[image]

Comment: Наверное, автор вопроса хотел "ужать" (то есть установить отступы по бокам) страницу, которая загрузиться во фрейм.

Comment: Может, просто "ужать" каждый фрейм?
Это можно сделать iframe'ами, будет проще.

Comment: @kirelagin Нужно, так сказать, "ужать" по вертикальной оси все то, что находится между начальным тегом <frameset> и конечным </frameset>, я просто вопрос не правильно поставил. Что фреймы зло, с вами согласен. @John Brown Cпасибо, умный человек :)  
@uramer239 Неплохой вариант, но если ужимать каждый фрейм, то они по умолчанию выравниваются по левому краю, а нужно по центру. И еще, немного непонятно, как iframe'ами ужать каждый фрейм, просветите :)

Comment: Нарисуйте картинку и прикрепите, чтобы было понятно, чего Вы хотите! :)

Answer (score 1):

frameset "ужать" таким образом не выйдет. Используйте iframe.

```
<iframe id="top"></iframe>
<iframe id="left"></iframe>
<iframe id="right"></iframe>
```